# Generate value of select box, based of value from other select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

I have two select box like this.

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="1">product 1</option>
    <option value="2">product 2</option>
    <option value="3">product 3</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
    <option value="1">sub product 1</option>
    <option value="2">sub product 2</option>
    <option value="3">sub product 1</option>
    <option value="4">sub product 1</option>
    <option value="5">sub product 3</option>
</select>
```

I want to create auto generate values of second select box based on we chose from first select box, ex I choose `product 1`, the second select box will only contain `sub product 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

Here is the working example: https://output.jsbin.com/ronoteb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var options="";
    $("#select1").on('change',function(){
        var value=$(this).val();
        if(value=="1")
        {
             options="<option>Select 2</option>"
                    +"<option value='1'>sub product 1</option>"
                    +"<option value='2'>sub product 2</option>";
            $("#select2").html(options);
        }
        else if(value=="2")
        {
            options="<option>Select 2</option>"
                    +"<option value='3'>sub product 3</option>"
                    +"<option value='4'>sub product 4</option>";
            $("#select2").html(options);
        }
        else if(value=="3")
        {
            options="<option>Select 2</option>"
                    +"<option value='5'>sub product 5</option>"
                    +"<option value='6'>sub product 6</option>";
            $("#select2").html(options);
        }
        else
            $("#select2").find('option').remove()
    });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="" selected>select</option>
  <option value="1">product 1</option>
  <option value="2">product 2</option>
  <option value="3">product 3</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is a static & very complex solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a data attribute like `data-parent` in `select2` for identifying which product's sub-product it is. Then in `select1` change event you can use `filter` method and the `data-parent` attribute to hide and show options like following.

```js
$('#select1').change(function() {
    var parent = $(this);
    
    var visibleOptions = $('#select2 option').hide().filter(function() {
         return $(this).data('parent') == parent.val();
    }).show();
            
    if(visibleOptions.length)
        visibleOptions.eq(0).prop('selected', true);
    else
        $('#select2').val('');
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
    <option value="1">product 1</option>
    <option value="2">product 2</option>
    <option value="3">product 3</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
    <option data-parent="1" value="1">sub product 1</option>
    <option data-parent="2" value="2">sub product 2</option>
    <option data-parent="1" value="3">sub product 1</option>
    <option data-parent="1" value="4">sub product 1</option>
    <option data-parent="3" value="5">sub product 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate the dropdown on `change` of another `select` dropdown, you can initially, generate the object containing `value` and `text` to display for the second dropdown.

Then on change of first select dropdown `value`, you can iterate through the array and populate the second dropdown.

```js
let selectOptions = {
  1: [{
    value : "1",
    text: "sub product 1"
   }],
  2: [{
    value : "2",
    text: "sub product 2"
   }],
   3: [{
    value : "3",
    text: "sub product 3"
   }]
}

$("#select1").change(function(){
  let select2 = $("#select2");
  select2.empty();
  console.log(selectOptions[$(this).val()]);
  selectOptions[$(this).val()].forEach(function(item){
    select2.append($("<option />").val(item.value).text(item.text));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="1">product 1</option>
  <option value="2">product 2</option>
  <option value="3">product 3</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
  <option value="1">sub product 1</option>
  <option value="2">sub product 2</option>
  <option value="3">sub product 3</option>
 <option value="4">sub product 4</option>
 <option value="5">sub product 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but i meant is , when i chose product 1 from first select box , the second select box will only contain sub product 1